# Catch ActionCable Connection Refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I've looked all around and can't find an answer to this issue.  How do I catch something like the following error in javascript?

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://clean.lvh.me:3000/cable' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is there a way for me to test if the connection is active?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't quite able to catch any errors around the ActionCable websocket connection, but I did figure out how to test if the connection is active using the data from the ActionCable object:

```
App.rooms.consumer.connection.disconnected
```

The value is `false` when connected and `true` when disconnected.

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: I have same pb (I use `ActionCable.createConsumer 'ws://localhost:28080'`), no solution? :(

Comment: I use the solution I mentioned above.  If you do something like App.rooms = App.cable.subscriptions.create(... then you can test if the connection is disconnected with: App.rooms.consumer.connection.disconnected == false.  It's not perfect but it works reasonably well.